# looking to make a group inside of a member page

Tags: php, sql

Looking for an structure of how to build a group inside pool of a members.

memeber are going to be group by interests fields rows. The memeber who has the same insterets fields value and nickname value will belong to certain group, they can join, be invited. also any member will have the power of forming or creating a group. how would be the database structure for that? so far I have a member tables to start with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a group table . Make a Member table  and 
have Group-id as an foreign key into the Member table 
that way you can list the number of members in a single group.

Have the nick name and value fields in the group and the power to make a group 
all these seems to be flags now it depends you can have 
member rights table or incorporate all that in to a single table.

hope that will at least give you an idea of db structure

Comment: Yes that's an start, thanks molvi, What do you mean by a flag?

Comment: what are the fields i am looking at the group table?